# Wifi AWUS036NH working in 10.9 but with no Internet

Tags: wifi

I have got a Mavericks (10.9) installation on a Mac and a AWUS036NH WiFi card. There are several drivers to get WiFi card working. There is one of them in this page (http://store.rokland.com/pages/support) and another in the bear extender page, device that uses the same chipset.

The thing is that I installed the driver and the tool that is installed does the wifi connection to the router, its says that its connected but when I use the browser or other application, there is not internet.

Airport is disabled.

I dont know what can I do.

Answer (score 1):

Try following [these instructions](http://osxdaily.com/2012/11/30/resolving-stubborn-wi-fi-connection-problems-in-mac-os-x/). Condensed version is below.

Turn off Wi-Fi.

Open Finder, press Command+Shift+G then enter the path below and click Go:

```
/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/
```

Find and delete the following files (some may not exist):

```
com.apple.airport.preferences.plist
com.apple.network.identification.plist
NetworkInterfaces.plist
preferences.plist
```

Reboot.